# get directory path from SDCARD ANDROID 6.0.1

Tags: android

After updating to Android 6.0.1 i can't find the files on my sdcard programmatically.

The SD Card directory shows now "storage/9C33-6BBD/"

After this path I has my data.
How i can get them ?

```
System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE")Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

Doesn't work

Before updating Androiud it works well.

Comment: You have not had direct arbitrary access to removable storage since Android 4.4.

Comment: ?? under Andoird 5 i can read and write data from external storage

Comment: You can read/write from `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, with the proper permissions. External storage is not removable storage.

Comment: Don't forget in Android 6 there is also a required runtime permission request in addition to being in manifest (external storage is a "dangerous" permission); external storage just got more tricksy to use....  See this answer for some details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow  See this topic for background https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: You can avoid these checks by setting target SDK lower than 23.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `getExternalFilesDirs()`. It will give two paths. The second one in on the sd card.